# Getting a value from an array in controller

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have a function in controller which contains an array

```
function get_art(){
$data['rec']=$this->article_model->get_article();
$this->load->view('first',$data);}
```

I need the section_id  from $data to pass it to another function in model.How can I get that?
Thanks from your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function get_art(){
   $data['rec']=$this->article_model->get_article();
   foreach ($data['rec'] as $a) {
     print_r($a->section_id); // $this->article_model->anotherfun($a->section_id);
   }
   $this->load->view('first',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In View you can simply access it like below.

```
        <?php echo $rec->section_id; ?>
```

But without viewing the model function I cannot determine whether you return an array or single object from the db read.